# SSL Protocal used by Browser to Send Request to Server

Tags: tomcat, servlets, ssl-certificate, tls1.2

I have a Servlet to which a client (Browser) can make a request. I want to know which SSL Protocol version is used for this request like, SSL / TLS / TLS 1.1 / TLS 1.2 in my servlet. Can anyone guide me through this.

I am using Java 8, Tomcat 8.5.9.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [source code](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/8.5.x/java/org/apache/coyote/AbstractProcessor.java#L784) (search for `populateSslRequestAttributes` if that link doesn't take you to the right place), Tomcat stores this information in the request attributes  `javax.servlet.request.cipher_suite` and `org.apache.tomcat.util.net.secure_protocol_version`.  So you should be able to just do:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                  HttpServletResponse response) {
    String cipherSuite = request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.cipher_suite");
    String protocolVersion = request.getAttribute("org.apache.tomcat.util.net.secure_protocol_version");
...
}
```

Realize that some of this has to do with the way you have Tomcat configured.  For example, I regularly place Apache in front of Tomcat and have a non-SSL connection from Apache to Tomcat.  Tomcat would not be able to give you the information you need in that case.

Comment: According to the Java Servlet Specification, Tomcat provides all this and much more besides, via further `javax.servlet.request.*` properties, and it does so whether or not an Apache HTTPD is in front and terminating the SSL connection. HTTPD provides it all to Tomcat.

Comment: @stdnubar
String protocolVersion = request.getAttribute("org.apache.tomcat.util.net.secure_protocol_version");

above line gives me SSL protocal version if i access my site directly i.e. without apache server in between, but if request is through apache then it gives null, do you know why is so?

Comment: @AmeySawant look here:  https://serverfault.com/questions/752336/how-do-i-get-apache-http-server-to-log-the-ssl-protocol-for-requests

Comment: It's worth pointing-out that the specific request attribute mentioned here - the one shows the protocol – is _not_ a part of the formal Servlet Specification. See [this issue](https://github.com/jakartaee/servlet/issues/130) for a proposal to add it to the servlet specification.